# Length of Band Around Tight 6 Cylinders

Tags: geometry

I ran into a problem that I think fairly well-known in the math olympic style community, but still couldn't find a quick and efficient way out of it. I wonder what the trick is.
[1]: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/diagram-band-stretched-tight-around-6-congruent-cylinders-radius-4-band-touches-cylinder-l-q38738101

What I have done is that I tried to calculate the angles between distances of centers of circles but the third side is not known. What's your take on this?
Thanks.
WY.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Length of string stretched around circles of identical radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197756/length-of-string-stretched-around-circles-of-identical-radius) - found in the "Related" section on the RHS. FYI, there's also a closely related question listed there of [String wrapping around 7 cylinders](/q/4058453).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint…the curved parts add up to one full circle

Comment: That's the trick. I didn't know it. Fairly new to this kind of geometry that involves translation, rotation, and such.. But why do they add up to the full circle ? I think by translating the circles to the same center and the curves parts fill the circumference. I think the total measure of the central angles subtended the curved parts add up to 360 degrees.

Comment: Yes and you can do this translation because the closest edge radii of two adjacent sectors are parallel (since tangent is perpendicular to radius)